# Install GDAL and GEOS libraries for Windows on Azure app service

Tags: python, django, azure, geodjango

I have an Azure App Service where I run a site built with Python3 and Django, connecting to a PostgreSQL database in a VM. Now I need to add geodjango support which needs native GEOS and GDAL libraries, and I can't get this to work.

Since I can't run the installer in the App Service I have made a local installation and copied all the files via FTP. I've set the environment variables:

```
OSGEO4W_ROOT=<dir>
GDAL_DATA=<dir>\share\gdal
PROJ_LIB=<dir>\share\proj
PATH=<dir>\bin
```

And I've set the django settings:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '<dir>/bin/geos_c.dll'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '<dir>/bin/gdal200.dll'
```

And still everything I get is `OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`.

Is this possible to solve?

Comment: How do you configure the system PATH on Azure Web Apps? It seems we don't have sufficient permission to do these operations.

Comment: I (try to) set it in `web.config`. If this is ignored due to permission restraints then that would explain my problems I guess :(